# Generic doubly linked list copy constructor efficiency and linkage

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having an issue with implementing the following two *constructors*:

```
List(const List& other)
~List()
```

Originally, the copy constructor was written as:

```
for (auto current = other._head._next; current != &other._head; current = current->_prev){
            push_back(static_cast<T*>(current));
        }
```

The above is considered **ineffective** and **inefficient**. So, I am trying to re-write it like this:

```
for (auto ptr = other._head._next; ptr != &other._head; ptr = ptr->_next)
        {
            T* item = new T(*dynamic_cast<T*>(ptr)));

            Link<T>* current = &_head;
            Link<T>* previous = &_head;

            current->_next = item;
            previous = current;

            /*
            
            // link to new head
            _head._next = other._head._next;
            _head._prev = other._head._prev;

            // Link prev och next to correct head
            _head._next->_prev = &_head;
            _head._prev->_next = &_head;
            
            */
        }
```

However, I am a total newbie on understanding how this Next, Prev, Next Prev, and finally connect together has to be done properly in the context of this copy constructor and the destructor. So, I am not sure why the above does not work and I am asking if someone know this and can help out here.

**Link.hpp**

```
template<class T>
class Link {
    template<class> friend class List;
    Link* _next, * _prev;
public:
    Link() : _next(this), _prev(this) {}
    virtual ~Link() {}
    T* next() const { return dynamic_cast<T*>(_next); }
    T* prev() const { return dynamic_cast<T*>(_prev); }

    T* insert_after(T* in)
    {
        in->_next = this;
        in->_prev = m_prev;
        _prev->_next = in;
        _prev = in;
        return in;
    }

    T* insert_before(T* in)
    {
        return _prev->insert_after(in);
    }

    T* remove()
    {
        _prev->_next = _next;
        _next->_prev = _prev;
        return dynamic_cast<T*>(this);
    }

    void splice_after(Link* f, Link* l)
    {
        if (f != l){
            f->_prev->_next = l->_next;
            last->_next->_prev = f->_prev;

            f->_prev = this;
            l->_next = this->_next;
            _next->_prev = l;
            _next = f;
        }
    }

    void splice_before(Link* f, Link* l)
    {
        m_prev->splice_after(f, l);
    }

    T* erase_first()
    {
        Link* tmp = _next;
        _next = _next->_next;
        _next->_prev = this;
        return static_cast<T*>(tmp);
    }

    T* erase_last() {
        Link* tmp = _prev;
        _prev = _prev->_prev;
        _prev->_next = this;
        return static_cast<T*>(tmp);
    }
};
```

**List.hpp:**

```
#include <string.h>

template<class T> 
class List {
    template<class X> class ListIter {
        template<class> friend class List;
        Link<T>* _ptr;
    public:
        // Typedefs
        typedef std::bidirectional_iterator_tag iterator_category;
        typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
        typedef std::remove_const_t<X>  value_type;
        typedef X* pointer;
        typedef X& reference;
    public:
        ListIter() : _ptr{ nullptr } {}
        ListIter(Link<T>* ptr) : _ptr{ ptr } {}
        ListIter(const ListIter& other) : _ptr{other._ptr} {}
        ListIter& operator=(const ListIter& other) 
        {
            _ptr = other._ptr;
            return *this;
        }

        X& operator*() { return *dynamic_cast<T*>(_ptr); }
        X* operator->() { return dynamic_cast<T*>(_ptr); }
        ListIter& operator++() { _ptr = static_cast<T*>(_ptr->_next); return *this; }
        ListIter& operator--(){ _ptr = static_cast<T*>(_ptr->_prev); return *this; }
        ListIter operator++(int) { auto r(*this); operator++(); return r; }
        ListIter operator--(int){ auto r(*this); operator--(); return r; }
        difference_type operator-(const ListIter& other) {
            return (_ptr - other._ptr);
        }

        friend auto operator<=>(const ListIter& lhs, const ListIter& rhs)
        {
            if ((lhs._ptr - rhs._ptr) < 0)
                return std::strong_ordering::less;
            else if ((lhs._ptr - rhs._ptr) > 0)
                return std::strong_ordering::greater;
            return std::strong_ordering::equivalent;
        }

        friend bool operator==(const ListIter& lhs, const ListIter& rhs)
        {
            return (lhs <=> rhs) == 0;
        }
    };

    Link<T> _head;

public:
    using iterator = ListIter<T>;
    using const_iterator = ListIter<const T>;

    List() 
    {
        _head._next = &_head;
        _head._prev = &_head;
    }
    
    List(const List& other) // Problem here, does not work, not sure how to get this solved.
    {
for (auto ptr = other._head._next; ptr != &other._head; ptr = ptr->_next)
        {
            T* item = new T(*dynamic_cast<T*>(ptr)));

            Link<T>* current = &_head;
            Link<T>* previous = &_head;

            current->_next = item;
            previous = current;

            /*
            
            // link to new head
            _head._next = other._head._next;
            _head._prev = other._head._prev;

            // Link prev och next to correct head
            _head._next->_prev = &_head;
            _head._prev->_next = &_head;
            
            */
    }
    }
    
    List(const char* other)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(other); ++i)
            _head.insert_after(new T(other[i]));
    }

    ~List()
    {
        while (_head._next != &_head)
        {
            pop_front();  // This isn't efficient. 
        }
    }

    T* pop_front() 
    {
        return _head.erase_first();
    }
    
    T* pop_back() 
    {
        return _head.erase_last();
    }

    void push_front(T* node) { _head.insert_before(node);}
    void push_back(T* node) { _head.insert_after(node);}
};
```

Comment: I suggest basing the logic around using the `List::insert_after` method, but first you need to make sure `List::insert_after` works correctly.

Comment: @user4581301, everything works correctly. I have tested this, the issue isn't with working incorrectly, but effective code.

Comment: @user4581301, please see: `void push_front(T* node)` and `void push_back(T* node)`

Comment: My problems: How does `Link` store a value? How does `insert_after` work if `T` is not always `Link`?

Comment: @user4581301, all code is available above, refer to **Link.hpp** and **List.hpp**, please.

Comment: I know that stuff already. Everything works as is, it's not concerning now. What is, is the Copy Constructor which takes a `List` and the destructor of the List, `~List()`

Comment: To elaborate on user458...s comment: Your `Link` class only has members indicating the next/previous elements, but no member variable that would allow you to store a value. Usually from a `Link` class (which I'd call `Node`), I expect 3 members: a pointer to the previous node, a pointer to the next node and one member containing the value. The third one seems to be missing. The fact that you have to use `dynamic_cast`, even though you're using a template is suspicious; no explicit casts should be necessary here. Also suspicious: `List::ListIter` being private...

Comment: @fabian: They're using a version of the curiously recurring template pattern (which normally allows compile-time polymorphism, though I don't think this benefits from that); any `T` used with `List` is required to be a subclass of `Link<T>`, `List` cannot accept instances of arbitrary classes, just classes *specifically* written to work with it. I'm not sure how many of their `dynamic_cast`s are needed (I've never used the CRTP before, and am not confident on how much `_head` being a plain `Link<T>`, not `T`, affects things), but done properly, CRTP shouldn't require `dynamic_cast` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: I think the design here is a terrible idea; it looks like you're using the curiously recurring template pattern, but relying on `dynamic_cast` is pointless if so (the whole point is to get compile-time polymorphism, which means a `static_cast` from `Link<T>` to `T` (which is a child of `Link<T>`) should always be safe, and if it's not (because maybe your `_head` is a placeholder of type `Link<T>`, not an instance of `T`?), it's because you've written code that incorrectly treats them equivalently. I might suggest a refactor into three components:

1. `T` - the user's chosen type, which need not inherit from any given class, where currently your use of the curiously recurring template pattern requires it to inherit from `Link<T>`
2. `Link<T>` - The platonic ideal of a forward and reverse linked element of a linked list with no associated value (used solely for `_head`), where `_prev` and `_next` are pointers to `Link<T>` that, aside from pointers to `_head`, always point to `Node<T>`s.
3. `Node<T>` - A child class of `Link<T>` that adds a `T` data member and very little else (to avoid overhead, almost all behaviors not related to `T` itself would be defined non-`virtual`ly on `Link<T>`)

With the three of those, plus appropriate `emplace*` methods, you have the same features you currently have:

1. `_head` can be a plain `Link<T>` (no need to store a dummy `T`, nor require uses to define a default constructor)
2. All other elements are `Node<T>`, and have the same overhead of your current `Link<T>` (one instance of `T` plus two pointers)
3. `T` can be of arbitrary type (`emplace*` methods means the construction of a `T` can be deferred until the moment the `Node<T>` is created, no copies or moves of `T` needed)

where #3 is a stealth improvement which I'll repeat:

- `T` can be of *arbitrary* type, not just subclasses of `Link<T>`

and you get the added benefit of:

- Hiding more of your implementation (`Link` and `Node` can be `private` helper classes, where right now `Link` must be part of your public API), avoiding a lot of back-compat constraints that come with more of the API publicly visible

---

Secondly, your code is perfectly effective, it's just mildly inefficient (setting four pointers via indirection per new element, when you could set just two per element, and two more at the end to establish the `List` invariant). It's still a `O(n)` copy operation, not the `O(n**2)` operation a Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm would involve.

---

Beyond that, taking your word that everything else works, all you need to do  to write a maximally efficient copy constructor is:

1. Begin with a pointer to the current element (`_head`), which I'll call `current_tail` (because at every stage of the copy, it's the logical tail of the list to date, and if no other element is found, it will be the real tail)
2. For each new element copied from `other`:

   1. Set its `_prev` to `current_tail` (because `current_tail` is the current tail of the `List`, creating the reverse linkage)
   2. Set `current_tail`'s `_next` to the new element (creating the forward linkage)
   3. Set `current_tail` to the new element (because now that they're linked to each other completely; we don't need a `previous` at all)
3. When you've copied everything per step 2, fix up the cycle, tying the final element to `_head` and vice-versa.

The end result is simpler than what you were writing (because you don't need a `previous` pointer at all):

```
List(const List& other) // Problem here, does not work, not sure how to get this solved.
{
    Link<T>* current_tail = &_head;   // 1. The tail of an empty list points to _head
    for (auto ptr = other._head._next; ptr != &other._head; ptr = ptr->_next)
    {
        T* item = new T(*dynamic_cast<T*>(ptr)));
        // We have validly forward linked list at each loop, so adding new element just means:
        item->_prev = current_tail ;  // 2.1. Telling it the prior tail comes before it
        current_tail->_next = item;   // 2.2. Telling the prior tail the new item comes after it
        current_tail = item;          // 2.3. Update notion of current tail
    }
    current_tail->_next = &_head;     // 3. Real tail's _next points to _head to indicate end of list
    _head._prev = current_tail;       // _head._prev is logical pointer to tail element, fix it up
    
}
```

You might need a couple casts sprinkled in there to deal the weirdness of `List<T>` also being `T` (and storing it with different types in different places), but otherwise that's it).

Voila, the only two uses of indirect variables per loop (both writes; all loads come from locals) rather than five (four written, one read; each reference to `_prev` is implicitly indirect use of `this->_prev`) involved when you `push_back` repeatedly.

For bonus points, write yourself a `swap` helper (using [the copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279550/364696)), which really only needs to change four items (`_head`'s `_next` and `_prev` to swap all the nodes of  each `List`, the `_next` of the tail element, and the `_prev` of the current head element to point to the `_head` of the new owning `List`), and about six lines of simple boilerplate will get you a cheap, efficient and safe move constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: Only differing variable names in my rewrite, so I'm not going to bother. On other small quasi-improvement: the default `Link` constructor does the smart thing and points `_prev` and `_next` to a safe parking location, but this gets in the way by adding an extra initialization in places where you already know where they're going to point and will assign later. You can't use `this` as a default argument, so there's a case to be made for an extra constructor that can eliminate the redundant  assignment.

Comment: @user4581301: I'll note, setting them to a safe parking location is fairly low cost (for practical purposes, it's local access; the memory is being touched to construct it in the first place), not real random pointer access, so I wouldn't worry about the cost. Setting them to real/useful values is also more important because this is part of your public API and you don't want to have user subclasses doing the wrong thing with them. If `Link<T>` was a private class, sure, do evil stuff to avoid writing them, but I'd be leery of writing a public class that doesn't force invariants.

Comment: Yeah, my smarter constructor suggestion doesn't work here due to the inheritance; otherwise,  `new Link(item->_prev)` would satisfy both worlds.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, can this be effectivized: `while (_head._next != &_head)
        {
            pop_front();  // This isn't efficient. 
        }`